# Como uso apis en AJAX?

Tags: ajax, api

Se usar ajax, pero para el examen que tengo en unas horas me piden usar ajax con alguna api y de ahi sacar la información, no tengo idea alguna, alguien me puede explicar como puedo hacerlo? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una API es una aplicacion web que sirve datos a los clientes, casi igual a una aplicacion web que utiliza ajax.

Puedes utilizar la API de prueba de [`jsonplaceholder`](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/). Por ejemplo, para obtener una lista de post con ajax solo tendrias que hacer lo siguiente:

```js
function cargarPosts(){
  $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", function(posts){
      console.log(posts);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="cargarPosts()">Cargar posts</button>
```

Ahi obtienes la lista de posts y puedes utilizar esos datos para crear una tabla con los mismos.